# Google protobuf: Recommended C++ library to handle the communication?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Is there such framework or lib? That will take care of the client/server sockets parts too?
Or just using something like BOOST::ASIO is the standard practice with protobuf?

Comment: I think you've already answered yourself: boost::asio

Comment: Boost.Asio is the hotness. Said differently, Boost.Asio++

Answer (score 5):

I use [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) together with protobuf.

Comment: Could you give me more details? ZeroMQ has many modes of operation and usage patterns

Answer (score 1):

I had hard time finding such a framework, so I wrote some (TLS) socket wrappers and a simple protobuf message channel. The library is available at [prototls](https://github.com/tlaitinen/prototls).

Answer (score 1):

I use **boost::asio** and **Poco::Net** with protobuf, you dont need a specific framework or library to use a protobuf message, you dont even have to use a protobuf message just on network only, it creates binary version of that message that means you can transfer that binary data thorught network, store it on a file etc.

I would recommend to build your own protocol just for the sake of learning socket programming :-) using whatever socket library you want, winsock, boost::asio, Poco::Net, etc, Where boost::asio is the easier one using the async_ methods. I build a network framework in 5 hours (server/client) with multithreading capabilities

Again like many people said, boost::asio is the way to go, having an extra library just for something really simple (with boost) it's a waste.